# Format JSON file in R: lexical error with character encoding

Tags: json, r

I have data that I retrieved from a server in JSON format. I now want to pre-process these data in R.

My raw .json file (if opened in a text editor) looks like this:

`{"id": 1,"data": "{\"unid\":\"wU6993\",\"age\":\"21\",\"origin\":\"Netherlands\",\"biling\":\"2\",\"langs\":\"Dutch\",\"selfrating\":\"80\",\"selfarrest\":\"20\",\"condition\":1,\"fly\":\"2\",\"flytime\":0,\"purpose\":\"na\",\"destin\":\"Madrid\",\"txtQ1\":\"I\'m flying to Madrid to catch up with friends.\"}"}`

I want to parse it back for further use to its intended format:

```
`{

"id": 1,

"data": {

  "unid": "wU6993",

  "age": "21",

  "origin": "Netherlands",

  "biling": "2",

  "langs": "Dutch",

  "selfrating": "80",

  "selfarrest": "20",

  "condition": 1,

  "fly": "2",

  "flytime": 0,

  "purpose": "na",

  "destin": "Madrid",

  "txtQ1": "I'm flying to Madrid to catch up with friends."

}

}`
```

Using `jsonlite` I can't read it in at all:

```
parsed = jsonlite::fromJSON(txt = 'exp1.json')
```

> ```
> Error in feed_push_parser(readBin(con, raw(), n), reset = TRUE) : 
>   lexical error: inside a string, '\' occurs before a character which it may not.
>           in\":\"Madrid\",\"txtQ1\":\"I\'m flying to Madrid to catch u
>                      (right here) ------^
> ```

I think the error tells me that some characters are escaped that should have been.

How can I solve this and read my file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have extra quotes around the nested braces defining `"data"`, the value of which is actually stored as one huge string instead of valid JSON. Take them out, and

```
my_json <- '{"id": 1,"data": "{\"unid\":\"wU6993\",\"age\":\"21\",\"origin\":\"Netherlands\",\"biling\":\"2\",\"langs\":\"Dutch\",\"selfrating\":\"80\",\"selfarrest\":\"20\",\"condition\":1,\"fly\":\"2\",\"flytime\":0,\"purpose\":\"na\",\"destin\":\"Madrid\",\"txtQ1\":\"I\'m flying to Madrid to catch up with friends.\"}"}'

my_json <- sub('"\\{', '\\{', my_json)
my_json <- sub('\\}"', '\\}', my_json)

jsonlite::prettify(my_json)
# {
#     "id": 1,
#     "data": {
#         "unid": "wU6993",
#         "age": "21",
#         "origin": "Netherlands",
#         "biling": "2",
#         "langs": "Dutch",
#         "selfrating": "80",
#         "selfarrest": "20",
#         "condition": 1,
#         "fly": "2",
#         "flytime": 0,
#         "purpose": "na",
#         "destin": "Madrid",
#         "txtQ1": "I'm flying to Madrid to catch up with friends."
#     }
# }
```